# Auto-closing columns in google tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script that will automatically hide the columns if line 69 is true in google tables

```js
function autohide() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name list');
  var val = sheet1.getRange('69:69').getValues();
  for (var j = 0, vLen = val.length; j < vLen; j++) {
    if (val[j]) sheet1.hideColumn(sheet1.getRange('69', j));
  }
}
```

I tried to write myself on this script unfortunately does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to hide columns when the cell value of row 69 is `true`.

#### Modification points:

- `getValues()` returns a 2-dimensional array. And, `var val = sheet1.getRange('69:69').getValues();` returns `[["A69", "B69",,,]]`. But, in your script, `if (val[j])` is used. In this case, it's 1 dimensional array.
- In the case of `sheet1.getRange('69', j)`, it is `sheet1.getRange(69, j + 1)`.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function autohide() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name list');
  var val = sheet1.getRange('69:69').getValues()[0];
  for (var j = 0, vLen = val.length; j < vLen; j++) {
    if (val[j] === true) sheet1.hideColumn(sheet1.getRange(69, j + 1));
  }
}
```

As another approach, I thought that the following modified script might be able to be used.

```js
function autohide() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name list');
  const val = sheet1.getRange(69, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  val.forEach((c, i) => {
    if (c === true) sheet1.hideColumns(i + 1);
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [hideColumn(column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)